# Not appending to URL on <a> click

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to append the Lang to the URL on clicking an anchor tag. I've an image in it. But, its not working. Here is my HTML. Is there anything wrong in the code?

```
<a href=\"?lang=en_US\"><img src="img/16.png"></a>
<a href=\"?lang=de_CH\"><img src="img/13.png"></a>
```

My actual URL is www.Plurals/examples/pigs_fallback.php. I want to append Lang to it as `www.Plurals/examples/pigs_fallback.php?lang=de_CH`

I think j query code is not necessary for this thing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `href=\"?lang=en_US\"` should be `href="?lang=en_US"`

Comment: @AshishKumar, not working.

Comment: This should, but I dont know why its not with you..

Comment: Can you post some fiddle If you dont mind? I want to add the parameter to the URL on clicking image tag.

Comment: @Rahul You said jQuery code? At the moment, I don't see any relationship with jQuery and what you've given us. Now, I'm assuming you have jQuery event for onclick for a tag which prevents from doing its usual thing (refering to e.preventDefault(); if you have that).   Check your jQuery code. Also, to clarify you, you don't necessarily need jQuery for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<a href="\?lang=en_US"><img src="img/16.png"></a>
<a href="\?lang=de_CH"><img src="img/13.png"></a>
```

Comment: I was doing a very very silly mistake. The images were in some other div element, for which the click event wasn't working.. Thanks Harshit.

Answer (score 2):

**Wrong Code:**

```
<a href=\"?lang=en_US\"><img src="img/16.png"></a>
<a href=\"?lang=de_CH\"><img src="img/13.png"></a>
```

**Correct Code:**

```
<a href="/examples/pigs_fallback.php?lang=en_US"><img src="img/16.png"></a>
<a href="/examples/pigs_fallback.php?lang=de_CH"><img src="img/13.png"></a>
```

Comment: exactly... but he is saying, this doesn't work. I dont understand why?

Comment: My URL would be like this.. http://localhost:8080/Plurals/examples/pigs_fallback.php.. I just want to add "?lang=de_CH" on an image click event.. It's not working @Nakka. I think I'm doing very nasty mistake.

Comment: Hi, I modified my answer.

Comment: @Nakka, you're redirecting it to the href url.. I just want to add the parameter to the existing url..

Answer (score 0):

Just use 
    href="?lang=en_US"
    href="?lang=de_CH"
No need to include page name in  tag.